# Seaborn Line Plot for plotting multiple parameters

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I have dataset as below,

| index | 10_YR_CAGR | 5_YR_CAGR | 1_YR_CAGR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1_rev | 20.5 | 21.5 | 31.5 |
| c2_rev | 20.5 | 22.5 | 24 |
| c3_rev | 21 | 24 | 27 |
| c4_rev | 20 | 26 | 30 |
| c5_rev | 24 | 19 | 15 |
| c1_eps | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| c2_eps | 21 | 24 | 25 |

This data has 5 companies and its parameters like rev, eps, profit etc. I need to plot as below:

rev:

- x_axis-> index_col c1_rev, ...c5_rev
- y_axis -> 10_YR_CAGR .. 1_YR_CAGR

eps:

- x_axis -> index_col: c1_eps,...c5_eps
- y_axis -> 10_YR_CAGR,... 1_YR_CAGR

etc...

I have tried with following code:

```
eps = analysis_df[analysis_df.index.str.contains('eps',regex=True)]

for i1 in eps.columns[eps.columns!='index']:
    sns.lineplot(x="index",y=i1,data=eps,label=i1)
```

I have to make a dataframe from source and then loop it. How can I try to create a for loop which loops from the main source dataframe itself?

Instead of creating a loop for separate parameters, how can I loop from the main source dataframe to create a chart of plots with parameters like rev, eps, profit to facegrid parameters? How to apply those filter in facetgrid?

My sample output of the above code,

[image]

How to plot the same sort of plot for different parameters in a single for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way facets are typically plotted is by "melting" your `analysis_df` into id/variable/value columns.

1. [**`split()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the `index` column into `Company` and `Parameter`, which we'll later use as id columns when melting:

   ```py
   analysis_df[['Company', 'Parameter']] = analysis_df['index'].str.split('_', expand=True)

   #      index  10_YR_CAGR  5_YR_CAGR  1_YR_CAGR  Company  Parameter
   #  0  c1_rev         100         21          1       c1        rev
   #  1  c2_rev           1         32         24       c2        rev
   # ...
   ```
2. [**`melt()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the CAGR columns:

   ```py
   melted = analysis_df.melt(
       id_vars=['Company', 'Parameter'],
       value_vars=['10_YR_CAGR', '5_YR_CAGR', '1_YR_CAGR'],
       var_name='Period',
       value_name='CAGR',
   )

   #      Company  Parameter      Period  CAGR
   #  0        c1        rev  10_YR_CAGR   100
   #  1        c2        rev  10_YR_CAGR     1
   #  2        c3        rev  10_YR_CAGR    14
   #  3        c1        eps  10_YR_CAGR     1
   # ...
   # 25        c2        pft   1_YR_CAGR    14
   # 26        c3        pft   1_YR_CAGR    17
   ```
3. [**`relplot()`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) `CAGR` vs `Company` (colored by `Period`) for each `Parameter` using the `melted` dataframe:

   ```py
   sns.relplot(
       data=melted,
       kind='line',
       col='Parameter',
       x='Company',
       y='CAGR',
       hue='Period',
       col_wrap=1,
       facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False},
   )
   ```

[image: relplot 3x1]

Sample data to reproduce this plot:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
csv = '''
index,10_YR_CAGR,5_YR_CAGR,1_YR_CAGR
c1_rev,100,21,1
c2_rev,1,32,24
c3_rev,14,23,7
c1_eps,1,20,50
c2_eps,21,20,25
c3_eps,31,20,37
c1_pft,20,1,10
c2_pft,25,20,14
c3_pft,11,55,17
'''
analysis_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))
```

Comment: thanks for the update, how to plot the graph row by row and use ylim based on plot instead of common ylim, so that chart look good?

Comment: You can use `col_wrap=1` to set 1 column (so 3 rows here) and `facet_kws={'sharey': False}` to unlink the y-axes. I edited my answer with these options.

Comment: Thanks @tdy it worked. But x labels are missing while doing this, only last chart shows xlabels. Any idea on how to update xlabels to all plots?

Comment: You're welcome. For the x-labels, you can unlink the x-axes as well: `facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False}` (answer updated)